# Question about iterating through a irritable loop resulting in index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

This works just fine

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for i in list_a:
    for h in range(1,list_a[i]):
        print(h)
```

but this does not work

```
months_b = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

for i in months_b:
    for h in range(1,months_b[i]):
        print(h)
```

getting error

"for h in range(1,months_b[i]):"

"IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: `i` takes values `31`, `28` etc. `months_b[31]` is out of range since `months_b` is only 12 in length. Maybe you want `for h in range(1, i)` ?

Comment: `for month in months_b: for day in range(1, month+1): print(day)`.

Comment: Your top code does *not* "work just fine": it fails with a similar IndexError.

Answer (score 1):

On your first pass through the loop with `months_b` your variable `i` is set to the first value of the list, so 31. Then you iterate over the list from index 1 to 31 and there are not 31 elements of the list. Therefore, index out of range.

Answer (score 1):

`for`*`variable`*`in`*`iterable`* iterates over elements, not indices.

You want to use something like this:

```
for month in months:
    for h in range(1,month):
        print(h)
```

Answer (score 0):

`range` is a list of natural numbers, in your case starting from 1 until `months_b[i]`. Since your `for` loop iterates over the elements of `months_b`, your first `i` will be 31. Therefore, your second loop will try to access the 31th element of `months_b`, which is out of range.